# Could not find starting boundary

Tags: aiohttp

**Describe the bug**

I am used `aiohttp` as a client and a server to File Uploads，The server raised an error when I add headers in post request。

```
Could not find starting boundary b'--dd7db5e4c3bd4d5187bb978aef4d85b1'
```

**To Reproduce**

environment

> python: 3.7.4
>
> aiohttp: 3.7.4.post0
>
> windows10

**server**

````
```python
    ...
    print("Enter form-data")
    print("req header: ", request.headers)
    data = await request.post()
    file_data = data["file"]
 ```
````

**client**

1、Not work

````
```python
 async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(
            url='http://{}:{}/mesh/recognize'.format(web_ip, web_port),
            data=file_data,
            headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=dd7db5e4c3bd4d5187bb978aef4d85b1'}
        ) as resp:
 ```
````

**console**:

```
> Enter form-data
> req header:  <CIMultiDictProxy('Host': '192.168.102.116:8000', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=dd7db5e4c3bd4d5187bb978aef4d85b1',  'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0', 'Content-Length': '364927')>
Could not find starting boundary b'--dd7db5e4c3bd4d5187bb978aef4d85b1'
** predict is Failed **
```

2、 work

````
 ```python
 async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(
            url='http://{}:{}/mesh/recognize'.format(web_ip, web_port),
            data=file_data) as resp:
 ```
````

**console**:

```
> Enter form-data
>req header:  <CIMultiDictProxy('Host': '192.168.102.116:8000', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0', 'Content-Length': '364927', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=dd7db5e4c3bd4d5187bb978aef4d85b1')>
out:  torch.float32
Predict result :tensor([[[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [5.0122, 4.7581, 4.8532,  ..., 4.7490, 4.6256, 4.8851]]]),
run time is 3054.393768310547ms
** predict is Successed! **
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a good-quality question on SO. You may get more guidance here: [ask]